# ARM7tdmi processor testing methodology

Tags: c++, arm

I'm currently writing an video game console emulator that is based on ARM7tdmi processor and I am almost in the stage that I wish to test if the processor is functioning correctly. I have only developed CPU and memory part of the entire console so only possible way to debug the processor is using logging (console) system. So far, I've only tested it simply by fetching dummy Opcodes and executing random instructions. Is there an actual ARM7 program (or other methodologies) that is specifically designed for this kind of purpose to make sure the processor is correctly functioning? Thanks in advance.

---

I used Dummy Opcodes such as,

ADD r0, r0,  r1,  LSL#2

MOV r1, #r0

But in 32 bit Opcode format.

Comment: Is this by any chance for the GBA or DS? I wrote an instruction test ROM for both consoles years ago (it's not a complete test though). I can see if I can dig them up if they'd be of use. They do require some basic emulation of the rest of the system (like the graphics processor). So if you wanted to log the output to a console instead, you'd have to modify the test source a bit.

Comment: Yep, GBA and DS. I'd be glad to receive any resources that can help me with development. Thanks.

Comment: [Here's the DS version](http://jiggawatt.org/armwrestler-ds.zip), comes with full source as well. I'll have to do a bit of searching to see if I still have the GBA version somewhere.

Comment: hah, I thought this ticket was closed and was answering in the comments, I see it is migrated...

Comment: where do we find this instruction set simulator to bang on?

Answer (score 2):

I also wrote some tests and found some bugs in a GBA emulator. I have also written my own emulators (as well as work in the processor business testing processors and boards).

I have a few things that I do regularly.  These are my general test methodologies.

There are a number of open source libraries out there, for example zlib and other compression libraries, jpeg, mp3, etc. It is not hard to bare metal these, fake an fopen, fread, fwrite with chunks of data and a pointer. the compression libs as well as encryption and hashes you can self test on the target processor. compress something, decompress it and compare the original with the uncompressed. I often will also run the code under test on a host, and compute the checksum of the compressed and decompressed versions, and give me a hardcoded check value which I then run on the target platform.  For jpeg or mp3 or hash algorithms I use a host version of the code under test to produce a golden value that I then compare on the target platform.

Before doing any of that though the flags are very tricky to get right, the carry flag in particular (and signed overflow), some processors invert the carry out flag when it is a subtract operation (subtract is an add with the second operand ones complemented and the carry in ones complemented (normal add without carry is a carry in of zero, subtract without carry then is an add with second operand inverted and a carry in of 1)). And that inversion of the carry out affects the carry on if the instruction set has a subtract with borrow, whether or not carry is inverted on the way in or not.

It is sometimes obvious from the conditional branch definitions (if C is this and V is that, if C is this and Z is that) for unsigned and signed variations of less than, greater than, etc as to how that particular processor manages the carry (unsigned overflow) and the signed overflow flags without having to experiment on real silicon. I dont memorize what processor does what, I figure it out per instruction set, so I dont know what ARM does.

ARM has nuances with the shift operations that you have to be careful that were implemented properly, read the pseudo code under each instruction, if shift amount == 32 then do this if shift amount == 0 then do that, otherwise do this other thing. with the arm7 you could do unaligned accesses if the fault was disabled and it would rotate the data around within the 32 bits, or something like that. If the 32 bits at address 0 was 0x12345678, then a 16 bit read at address 1 would give you something like 0x78123456 on the bus and the destination would then get 0x3456.  Hopefully most folks didnt rely on that.  But that and other "UNPREDICTABLE RESULTS" comments in the ARM ARM, changed from ARM ARM to ARM ARM (If you have some of the different hardcopy manuals this will be more obvious, the old white covered one (the skinny one as well as the thick one) and the blue covered one).  So depending on the manual you read (for those armv4 processors) you were sometimes allowed to do something and sometimes not allowed to do something. So you might find code/binaries that do things you think are unpredictable, if you only rely on one manual.

Different compilers generate differen code sequences so if you can find different arm compilers (clang/llvm and gcc being obvious first choices), get some eval copies of other compilers if you can (Kiel is probaby a good choice, now owned by arm I think it contains both Kiel and the RVCT arm compilers).  Compile the same test code with different optimization settings, test every one of those variations, and repeat that for each compiler.  If you only use one compiler for testing you will leave gaps in instruction sequences as well as a number of instructions or variations that will never be tested because the compiler never generates them.  I hit this exact problem once.  Using open source code you get different programmer habits too, whether it is asm or C or other languages different individuals have different programming habits and as a result generate different instruction sequences and mixes of instructions which can hide or expose processor bugs.  If this is a single person hobby project you eventually will rely on others.  The good thing here being a gba or ds or whatever emulator when you start using roms you will have a large volume of other peoples code, unfortunately debugging that is difficult.

I heard some hearsay ones that intel/x86 design validation folks use operating systems, various ones, to beat on their processors, it creates a lot of chaos and variation.  Beats up on the processor but like the roms, extrememly difficult to debug if something goes wrong.  I have personal experience with that with caches and such running linux on the processors I have worked on.  Didnt find the bug until we had Linux ported and booting, and the bug was crazy hard to find...fortunately the arm7tdmi does not have a cache.  If you have a cache then take those combinations I described above, test code multiplied by optimization level multiplied by different compilers, and then add to that in the bootstrap or other places compile a version with one, two, three, four, nops or other data such that the alignment of the binary changes relative to the cache lines causing the same program to exercise the cache differently.

In this case where there is real hardware you are trying to emulate you can do things like have a program that generates random alu machine code, generate dozens of instructions with randomly chosen source and destination registers, randomize add, subtract, and, or, not, etc.  randomize the flags on and off, etc.  pre-load all the registers, set the flags to a known state, run that chunk of code and then capture the registers and flags and see how it compares to real hardware.  You can produce an infinite amount of separate tests, various lengths, etc.  easier to debug this than to debug a code sequence that does some data or flag thing that is part of a more complicated program.

Take that combination of test programs, multplied by optimization setting, multiplied by compiler, etc.  And beat on it with interrupts.  Vary the rate of the interrupts.  since this is a simulator you can do something I had hardawre for one time.  In the interrupt, examine the return address, compute an address that is some number of instructions out ahead of that address, remember that address.  Return from the interrupt, when you see that address being fetched fire a prefetch abort, have the prefetch abort code, stop watching that address when the prefetch abort fires (in the simulation) and have the code for the prefetch abort handler return to where the abort happend (per the arm arm) and let it continue.  I was able to create a fair amount of pain on the processor under test with this setup...particularly with the caches on...which you dont have on an arm7tdmi.

Note that a high percentage of the gba games are thumb mode because on that platform, which used mostly 16 bit wide data busses, thumb mode ran (much) faster than arm mode even though thumb code takes about 10-15% more instructions.  as well as taking less rom space for the binary.  Carefully examine the blx instruction as I think there are different implementations based on architecture armv4 is different than armv6 or 7, so if you are using an armv6 or 7 manual as a reference or hardware for validating against, understand those differences.

blah, blah, blah  TL; DR. sorry for rambling this is a fun topic for me...